# Converting styles from ArcGIS Pro (.stylx) to ArcMap (.style)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, style-manager

I want to open .stylx file from ArcGIS Pro in ArcMap.

Is there any tool in ArcGIS Pro to convert .stylx files to .style format?

Comment: What could you see when you treated this file as an MDB file?

Comment: Each style is shown as a table.I have imported other styles and make a query selection based on codes to find the difference.Query runs and result are shown as code, name & description.What i need is the symbolgy also.

Comment: Please include those details in your question.

Comment: Is there a way to convert styles from ArcPro (.stylx)  to ArcMap (.style) ?
I want to open .stylx file in Arcmap. Any tool in ArcPro to convert files to .style format?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any additional details that you think potential answerers may need.

Answer (score 4):

If you have ArcGIS Portal set up you can send the ArcGIS Pro layer to the portal as a web layer. Then through the web browser interface of the portal you can go to the web layer and click "Open in ArcGIS Desktop". That will open the layer file in ArcMap and you can save the styles, or export a layer file from ArcMap that will retain the styles in ArcMap format.

Comment: @user134507 this works great and was what I went with. Unfortunately it makes all the symbols into picture symbols, something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

The [ArcGIS Pro documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/projects/connect-to-a-style.htm) says:

> Styles created in previous versions of ArcGIS Desktop can be used in
>   ArcGIS Pro. Importing the style simultaneously creates an updated
>   *.stylx version of the style and adds it to the project.

It is clear that ArcGIS Pro can import styles (`*.style`) from the older ArcMap architecture but I would not expect ArcMap to be able to import styles (`*.stylx`) from the newer ArcGIS Pro architecture.

If you need to share styles between ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro then I recommend that you create them using ArcMap as `*.style` files.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the SLYR plugin says:

- "Support for converting ArcGIS Pro .stylx symbol libraries to and from QGIS symbol libraries (coming December 2021)
- Support for ArcGIS Pro .lyrx conversion (coming December 2021)"

(Source: https://north-road.com/slyr/)

Maybe it will be considered in the free versión soon...