# Exporting ArcGIS Pro Style file

Tags: arcgis-pro

New user to ArcGIS Pro here.
I was wondering if it was possible to export/convert the ArcGIS Pro .stylx file type to another format? Nothing specific, just another file type so that it can be used elsewhere.

I have seen a few links like the one below about converting it back to .style but its still a Esri format.
[Converting styles from ArcGIS Pro (.stylx) to ArcMap (.style)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224549/converting-styles-from-arcgis-pro-stylx-to-arcmap-style)

Comment: SLYR: the ESRI to QGIS Compatibility Suite is going to be the closest tool for what your requesting  https://north-road.com/slyr/ "We also have plans to extend SLYR to support the newer ArcGIS Pro LYRX and MAPX formats,"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried SLYR but its not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like that functionality exists. I'm sure esri wants to keep folks using ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: .stylex are an SQLite database. Examine and export with a tool like DBeaver. However decoding the binary contents is still a remaining exercise. https://i.imgur.com/KXssLxj.png