ESRI .stylx import under QGIS
I want to import .stylx files from ESRI under QGIS and convert to .qml
Only plugin I found is the following: SLYR (Community Edition). It is edited by North Road:
https://north-road.com/slyr/
However, this plugin is not free. Conversion is blocked:

"This algorithm is available in the licensed version of SLYR only - please see https://north-road.com/slyr/ for details
Execution failed after 0.02 secondes"

Any work around method to convert .sly or .stylx files into open formats?

"While we fully intend to make the full SLYR plugin open source and freely publish the style/LYR/MXD conversion tools, we also require financial backing in order to support the significant time required to completely reverse engineer these file formats."

"International (non-Australian) entities: €1500 or USD$1650" This is obviously too much for a single use file conversion. Plus, on the principle, that means plugins can be locked up? I thought this was not possible on an open source environment.

note that ArcMap .style can be freely converted with SLYR (Community Edition). If it's single use then it's up to you to determine if recreating the style manually is cheaper than buying a licence…

J.R, the tool "Convert stylx to QGIS style XML" does not work: as I wrote in my question, is says "This algorithm is available in the licensed version of SLYR only". If you have a solution with this plugin, please explain. When I say single use, let's say, not so many uses. And even one file can be a burden to recreate manually.

You don't have two questions, you have a statement and a question.

What I mean was that while .stylx can't by converted .style can. So if you are willing and able to convert between the two (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224549/converting-styles-from-arcgis-pro-stylx-to-arcmap-style) you may have a workaround...

@Vince, text modified so first question looks like a question.

@J.R, thank you it's clear. Well it's a workaround that can be tried. But that still requires Esri suite though, to convert from .stylx to .style.

The issue is that we have a One question per Question policy (as per the [Tour]), so a numbered list of questions is likely to result in closure. Discussion of whether a vendor is adhering to licensing policy is off-topic here.

Your first question is answered here : https://blog.qgis.org/2016/05/29/licensing-requirements-for-qgis-plugins/ (in short, you need to made the plugin source code available to all plugin user, you can sell your plugin as long as you make  the sources of your plugin available under the same license as QGIS to each purchaser)
